# Concatenate multiple columns and skip blanks

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to concatenate 8 columns to one.
There are a lot of blanks in each column. I want to skip or just not showing the blanks in the combined column.

I tried this code:

```
df['combined']=df.apply(
                        lambda x:'%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%s_%s'
                          % (x['a'],x['b'],x['c'],x['d'],x['e'],x['f'],x['g'],x['h']),
                        axis=1)
```

The result is as following:

```
combined
0
1
2        type1
3
4        type2
5
6        type8
...
```

I want to delete the leading numbers and the blanks. I am expecting to get the combined column like `'type1type2type8'`

Comment: `df['combined'] = df.loc[:, 'a':'h'].agg('_'.join, axis=1)` would probably be better.

Answer (score 1):

The code below can avoid missing values -

```
df['combined'] = df.apply( lambda x: x['a':'h'].str.cat(sep='_'), axis=1 )
```

Answer (score 0):

I would:
`df['combined'] = df.apply( lambda x: x['a':'h'].str.concat(sep='_'), axis=1 )`.
has the benefit of built in `nan` handling... and avoid the acane-ness of `agg()`